# IMAP client library in Erlang to query IMAP servers

Tags: erlang, imap

Is there any working IMAP client library implemented in Erlang which can query IMAP servers?

Comment: Seems a simple inquiry of fact, is there a working IMAP library for Erlang - and the answer - as it currently stands, is no.

Comment: https://github.com/MainframeHQ/switchboard is apparently an IMAP client in Erlang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[erlmail](http://code.google.com/p/erlmail/) easily found on [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=erlang+imap+client)

Comment: That's a server implementation, not a client.

Answer (score 0):

there is another one [erlimap](https://github.com/jimenezrick/erlimap). But work is in progress.

Comment: Link in dead - a project of that name can be found here : https://github.com/boorad/erlimap