# Mature IMAP library

Tags: linux, unix, erlang, imap

I am working on a (linux) application which is going to interface with an IMAP server. However, I am having a surprisingly hard time finding a mature IMAP library. The language dosn't matter as long as its free and open source.

I am not an IMAP expert but I would really like it to support RFC 5032 which makes me able to pull a single message from the server.

The optimal solution would be if I could just send a query to the library and it would return the whole e-mail (and headers) as a string. It sound very simple but as I said I am having a really hard time finding one.

PS: I tried using Pythons but without any luck. It just crashes when I send a WITHIN query. I'm thinking about Java but I do not know anything about it and would like to hear you first. My application is being developed in erlang which has no mature libraries.

Comment: Duplicate question: for Erlang already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866956/any-erlang-library-to-query-imap-servers

Comment: I disagree. I asked for a mature library which supported IMAP extensions such as the WITHIN query. erlmail is barley usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you just need to know the right place to look. Many of the programming languages that run on Linux have their own website that lists open source libraries.

Here are some of the main sites, along some IMAP libraries that I found (for some languages there are many, many libraries available):

- [Erlang (CEAN)](http://cean.process-one.net/packages/index.yaws?action=filter&seek=imap): [erlmail](http://code.google.com/p/erlmail/)
- [Perl (CPAN)](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=imap&mode=all): [Net::IMAP::Client](http://search.cpan.org/~ganglion/Net-IMAP-Client-0.9501/lib/Net/IMAP/Client.pm)
- [Python (PyPI)](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=imap&submit=search): [IMAPClient](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/IMAPClient/0.7)
- [Ruby (RubyGems.org)](http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=imap): [imapget](http://rubygems.org/gems/imapget)
- [Haskell (HackageDB)](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html): [HaskellNet](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaskellNet)
- [Javascript/Node.js (NPM)](http://search.npmjs.org/): [imap](http://search.npmjs.org/#/imap)

I can't offer any advice as to the quality of these libraries, and you may need to browse through the libraries available for each language before you find one that has the features you need, but hopefully these links will lead you to a solution.